# pass recovery to upper goroutine golang

Tags: go

I created an example where I  run function concurrently inside which I panic and recover:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // "main" recovery
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("main goroutine paniced:", r)
        }
    }()

    // running function concurrently inside which I panic
    chanStr := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        // this "internal" goroutin recovery
        defer func() {
            if r := recover(); r != nil {
                fmt.Println("internal goroutine paniced:", r)
            }
            chanStr <- "hello world"
        }()
        // panicking and wanting recovery not only in "internal" recovery but in "main" recovery as well
        panic("NOT main goroutine")
    }()
    // waiting for chan with "internal" goroutine panicking and recovery
    str := <-chanStr
    fmt.Println(str)

    // panic("main")
}
```

It gives output:

```
internal goroutine panicked: NOT main goroutine
hello world
```

Is it possible to change my code to make pass recovery from "internal" to "main"? In other words I want it to write down to console:

```
internal goroutine paniced: NOT main goroutine
main goroutine paniced: main
hello world
```

I tried to implement this by removing "internal" recovery func at all, but "main" recovery do not recover panic inside "internal" goroutine in this case.

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MXKSUZVzRr)

## Update

I tried to follow @Momer's advice and  send an error through the channel and handle it in the main goroutine, instead of trying to bubble the panic up:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // "main" recovery
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("main goroutine paniced:", r)
        }
    }()

    // running func concarantly inside which I panic
    chanStr := make(chan string)
    chanErr := make(chan error)
    var err error
    go func() {
        // this "internal" goroutin recovery
        defer func() {
            if r := recover(); r != nil {
                fmt.Println("internal goroutine paniced:", r)
                switch t := r.(type) {
                case string:
                    fmt.Println("err is string")
                    err = errors.New(t)
                case error:
                    fmt.Println("err is error")
                    err = t
                default:
                    fmt.Println("err is unknown")
                    err = errors.New("Unknown error")
                }

                chanErr <- err
                chanStr <- ""
            }
        }()
        // panicing and wanting recovery not only in "internal" recovery but in "main" recovery as well
        panic("NOT main goroutine")
        chanStr <- "hello world"
        chanErr <- nil

    }()
    // waiting for chan with "internal" goroutin panicing and recovery
    str := <-chanStr
    err = <-chanErr
    fmt.Println(str)
    fmt.Println(err)

    // panic("main")
}
```

It gives error

```
all goroutines are asleep - deadlock
```

Full output:

```
go run /goPath/parentRecoverty2.go
internal goroutine paniced: NOT main goroutine
err is string
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
    /goPath/parentRecoverty2.go:48 +0x1d4

goroutine 5 [chan send]:
main.func·002()
    /goPath/parentRecoverty2.go:37 +0x407
main.func·003()
    /goPath/parentRecoverty2.go:42 +0x130
created by main.main
    /goPath/parentRecoverty2.go:46 +0x190
exit status 2
```

[Update playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZlLd79UIge)

Comment: Instead of trying to bubble the panic up, why not send an error through the channel and handle it in the main goroutine?

Comment: @Momer I have tried it but have error `all goroutines are asleep - deadlock`, please see my update above.

Comment: the second write (in your recover) blocks because nobody is there to read from the channels. you're about to write into them multiple times, but read only once.

Comment: @flx why write multiple times? I write once in `chanErr` and once in `chanStr` in second recovery block: `chanErr <- err
    chanStr <- ""`

Answer (score 2):

I took panic/recover in golang as try/catch/final blocks in java or c++.

For more detail, you can visit [Handling panics (from Golang spec)](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics).

so you can pass a panic to method's caller. 
a simple code is below, hope it helps

Note: in function Foo(), I use recover() to catch things going wrong, and then re-panic in order to catch it later in outer caller.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func Foo() {
    defer func() {
        if x := recover(); x != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Runtime panic: %v \n", x)
            panic("Ah oh ... Panic in defer")
        }
    }()
    panic("Panic in Foo() !")
}

func Game() {
    defer func(){
        fmt.Println("Clean up in Game()")
    }()

    defer func() {
        if x := recover(); x != nil {
            fmt.Println("Catch recover panic !!! In Game()")
        }
    }()
    Foo()

}

func main() {

    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("Program Quit ... ")
    }()

    fmt.Println("-----------Split-------------")
    go Game()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("-----------Split-------------")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your updated question, one thread is blocked by reading from `chanStr` while the other thread is blocked by writing into `chanErr`.
Switching the order of writes should resolve the deadlock.

```
defer func() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        fmt.Println("internal goroutine paniced:", r)
        switch t := r.(type) {
        case string:
            fmt.Println("err is string")
            err = errors.New(t)
        case error:
            fmt.Println("err is error")
            err = t
        default:
            fmt.Println("err is unknown")
            err = errors.New("Unknown error")
        }
        chanStr <- ""
        chanErr <- err
    }
}
```